# Discord.py Bot Link returns No Scopes even though I added scopes

Tags: discord.py, bots, scopes, invite

After coding a bot in Discord.py, while generating an invite link, I've added all the scopes and I was able to go through and authorize the bot. Then, while inviting it to the server, it gives this page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j0wz.png)

There are scopes added on the Discord Developer Portal, so this error doesn't make sense.

The first time I did this without the redirect URL (which I am using: https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize), it did work, and I was able to invite it into a test server. Now, I am trying to add it into the main server and it requires me to use the redirect URL, and it does not work anymore.

Can someone explain what is happening with this error and/or explain how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me due to copy / pasting the link between applications and something malformed the `GET` parameters to be `&amp;` which caused the `No Scopes Were Provided` popup.  Regenerating the link and ensuring it's only `&` separated should fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you! Found this in my redirect_url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

- -> Discord Developer Portal
- -> Your application
- -> OAuth
- -> URL Generator
- -> Select the **Bot** scope
- -> Select all the permissions you want at the bottom in the 'Bot permissions' that should have appeared
- -> Copy the link at the bottom and go to that

I've never had any issues doing that to invite a bot to one of my servers. Shouldn't need a redirect URL either.

Comment: I've followed those exact steps, but they return the same error as it requires a REDIRECT URL?
[imagelink](https://imgur.com/a/APYgq9X)

Comment: I made a new application and it seems to have worked... This is an interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  disabling **"REQUIRES OAUTH2 CODE GRANT"** option in bot options in the developer page of discord, this should fix the problem because disables OAUTH2.